# How to put line plot and scatter plot on the same plot in?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot scatter with over lined line plot. I have two sets of data and if I plot both of them as scatter plots it works, but if I try to plot the second one as a line graph (connected scatter plot), it won't even show.

```
plt.scatter(column1,column2,s=0.1,c='black')
plt.plot(column3,column4, marker='.', linestyle=':', color='r',)
```

(I tried using plt.scatter, I tried changing the markers and linestyle, tried without these as well and I still can't get it to work, I sometimes get the dots, but once I want them to be connected they disappear or nothing happens.)

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

That's what I get:
[Plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMZF.png)

Comment: I removed the tag, added it by mistake.

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using? For me, overlaying `plt.scatter` and `plt.plot` works fine.

Comment: @McLawrence 2.0.0

Comment: Can you give more detail about your data. Maybe all the scattered data is plotted over the lineplot. Try reversing both plot commands.

Comment: So, the black is whats supposed to be the scatter plot, and the red should be the lineplot? `linestyle='-'`makes no difference?

Comment: @McLawrence Yes, the red should be the lineplot. No, adding linestyle makes no difference.

Answer (score 10):

`matplotlib` simply overlays plot commands in the called order as long as you do not create a new `figure`.

As an example, try this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)

N = 100
x = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)
y = 0.9 * np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='green')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.power(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), 2), c= "red", marker='.', linestyle=':')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I get one figure with both data sets on, I just can't get the second 'scatter' to be a line graph, no matter what I do. Even if I plot it separately.

Comment: So, the example code produces a different output for you? Or the example picture does not look like the result you want to have?

Comment: Can you upload the plot you get and describe how the plot you want should look like in more detail?

Comment: If I copy and paste any plots from the internet it works, but as soon as I use my data it doesn't. I also tried with only parts of the data, but I have the same problem.

Comment: could you upload you're data somewhere. I am afraid otherwise I cannot reproduce your error.